# I am developing a chat application on android using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, chat

i want to save chat between two users by this command

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReferenceMessage.child("messages").child(mEmail).child(currentReceiverEmail).push().setValue(messages);
```

**message object**

```
private String id;
private String text;
private String senderEmail;
```

**messages** node is already created but **mEmail** email of sender and **currentReceiverEmail** email of receiver are not. I want these two nodes created when two users chat with each other for the first time and save the later chats in this node. is there any way i can do it. I am using this structure so that i can retrieve chat between any two users easily.
and If there is a better way to store chats between two users on firebase do mention it.

Comment: If you set up firebase rules correctly, I believe it should work as it is and create intermediate nodes automatically for you. Could you share the rules for this?

Comment: i haven't changed the default rules. @user1431765

Answer (score 0):

Refer the Github repos of firebase. They will surely help you:

https://github.com/firebase/firechat

https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/database

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
   public class Activity_Message extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


EditText msg;
String To_Name,To_Id;
String My_Name,My_Id;
Firebase reference1, reference2;



@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.message_list);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    reference1 = new Firebase("https://chatapp-e1eabdgdfg.firebaseio.com/Message/" + My_Name + "_" + To_Name);
    reference2 = new Firebase("https://chatapp-e1eabgfggf.firebaseio.com/Message/" + To_Name + "_" + My_Name);
    initViews();

    loadData();
}



private void initViews() {


    msg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg_edit);
    ImageView send = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);




    reference1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            //get data here


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //Log.d("fdfddhjChild Changed",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }


    });



}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.send_btn:

            String messageText = msg.getText().toString();
            if(!messageText.equals("")){
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("message", messageText);
                map.put("from_id", My_Id);
                map.put("to_id", To_Id);
                map.put("date_time", currDate);

                reference1.push().setValue(map);
                reference2.push().setValue(map);

            }

            msg.setText("");

            break;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is the structure of Firebase class and loaddata() function?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Activity_Message extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


EditText msg;
String To_Name,To_Id;
String My_Name,My_Id;
Firebase reference1, reference2;



@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.message_list);

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    reference1 = new Firebase("https://chatapp-e1eabdgdfg.firebaseio.com/Message/" + My_Name + "_" + To_Name);
    reference2 = new Firebase("https://chatapp-e1eabgfggf.firebaseio.com/Message/" + To_Name + "_" + My_Name);
    initViews();

    loadData();
}



private void initViews() {


    msg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg_edit);
    ImageView send = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.send_btn);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);




    reference1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            //get data here


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //Log.d("fdfddhjChild Changed",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }


    });



}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.send_btn:

            String messageText = msg.getText().toString();
            if(!messageText.equals("")){
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("message", messageText);
                map.put("from_id", My_Id);
                map.put("to_id", To_Id);
                map.put("date_time", currDate);

                reference1.setValue(map);
                reference2.setValue(map);





            }

            msg.setText("");

            break;

    }
}
}
```

Try this code....